# How to refer a job candidate when you're planning to leave for a new job soon

Tags: recruitment, resignation

I've been offered and accepted a new job, which I'm excited about. The offer is conditional on a background check, so I'm waiting to give my two weeks notice and should be doing that next week.

Recently, a friend has been looking for a new job and I was able to convince them to apply for a position on my project. Personally, I think he would be a decent replacement for myself.

Will it come across as dishonest if I submit them as a referral and then resign a few days later? Will my impending resignation reflect poorly on my friend? Is there any reason for me to suggest them as a candidate after I give notice?

I tried to find a referral tag, but couldn't.

Comment: If everything goes to plan, the company loses one employee and gains one employee. If you don't refer him, the company loses one employee. It's better for the company if you refer him.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you have made other plans theoretically shouldn't interfere with the recommendation. People are people and someone may be grumpy about it, but the recommendation is still more likely to help your friend than tonhurt him or her.